# Checkbox required in form. React using EmailJS

Tags: reactjs, validation, email, checkbox

I have a React project where I am using EmailJS, and I need the checkbox to be required before sending the form, or register the value of the checkbox in the email template. It's value is currently not being registered.

This is some of the code:

```
const ApplyForm = (props) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    student_name: "",
    adress: "",
    postnr: "",
    city: "",
    birthday: "",
    otherschool: "",
    startdate: "",
    firstgrade: "",
    secondgrade: "",
    thirdgrade: "",
    fourthgrade: "",
    fifthgrade: "",
    sixthgrade: "",
    seventhgrade: "",
    mom_name: "",
    mom_adress: "",
    mom_postnr: "",
    mom_city: "",
    mom_phone: "",
    mom_email: "",
    children_age: "",
    other: "",
    why: "",
  });

  const [formError, setFormError] = useState();
  const [formSuccess, setFormSuccess] = useState();

  function validateEmail(email) {
    const regEX = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    const patternMatches = regEX.test(email);
    return patternMatches;
  }

  const validateForm = () => {
    if (formData.student_name.length < 3) {
      setFormError("ERROR! Navn må inneholde minst 3 karakterer");
      setTimeout(() => {
        setFormError(null);
      }, 5000);
      return false;
    } else if (!validateEmail(formData.mom_email)) {
      setFormError("ERROR! Fyll inn en gyldig e-postadresse");
      setTimeout(() => {
        setFormError(null);
      }, 5000);
      return false;
    } else if (formData.adress.length < 3) {
      setFormError("ERROR! Adressen må inneholde minst 3 karakterer");
      setTimeout(() => {
        setFormError(null);
      }, 5000);
      return false;
    } else if (formData.postnr.length < 4) {
      setFormError("ERROR! Fyll inn et gyldig postnummer");
      setTimeout(() => {
        setFormError(null);
      }, 5000);
      return false;
    } else if (formData.city.length < 2) {
      setFormError("ERROR! Fyll inn poststed");
      setTimeout(() => {
        setFormError(null);
      }, 5000);
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (validateForm()) {
      send("service_loremipsum", "template_loremipsum", formData, "loremipsum")
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("SUCCESS!", response.status, response.text);
          setFormSuccess("Søknaden har blitt sendt!");
          setFormData({
            student_name: "",
            adress: "",
            postnr: "",
            city: "",
            birthday: "",
            otherschool: "",
            startdate: "",
            mom_name: "",
            mom_adress: "",
            mom_postnr: "",
            mom_city: "",
            mom_phone: "",
            mom_email: "",
            children_age: "",
            other: "",
            why: "",
            consent: "",
          });
          setTimeout(() => {
            setFormSuccess(null);
          }, 5000);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("FAILED...", err);
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Søk skoleplass</h1>
      <Container fluid>
        <Row className="justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <Col md={6}>
            <h2 className="form_h2">Opplysninger om eleven</h2>
            {formError && <p className="setFormError">{formError}</p>}
            {formSuccess && <p className="setFormSuccess">{formSuccess}</p>}
            <form className="apply_form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
              <fieldset>
                <label htmlFor="student_name" id="student_name">
                  Fullt navn
                </label>
                <input
                  className="apply_input"
                  type="text"
                  id="student_name"
                  name="student_name"
                  value={formData.student_name}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="adress" id="adress">
                  Adresse
                </label>
                <input
                  className="apply_input"
                  type="text"
                  id="adress"
                  name="adress"
                  value={formData.adress}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <div className="post_group">
                  <label htmlFor="postnr" id="postnr">
                    Postnummer
                  </label>
                  <input
                    className="apply_input"
                    type="text"
                    id="postnr"
                    name="postnr"
                    value={formData.postnr}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />{" "}
                </div>
                <div className="post_group">
                  <label htmlFor="city" id="city">
                    Poststed
                  </label>
                  <input
                    className="apply_input"
                    type="text"
                    id="city"
                    name="city"
                    value={formData.city}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <label htmlFor="birthday" id="birthday">
                  Fødselsdag
                </label>
                <input
                  className="apply_input"
                  type="date"
                  id="birthday"
                  name="birthday"
                  value={formData.birthday}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="otherschool" id="otherschool">
                  Skal barnet meldes ut av en annen skole? Hvilken?
                </label>
                <input
                  className="apply_input"
                  type="text"
                  id="otherschool"
                  name="otherschool"
                  value={formData.otherschool}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="startdate" id="startdate">
                  Dato for ønsket oppstart
                </label>
                <input
                  className="apply_input"
                  type="text"
                  id="startdate"
                  name="startdate"
                  value={formData.startdate}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label className="class_section">Søker til klassetrinn:</label>
                <section className="grade">
                  {" "}
                  <section className="class">
                    {" "}
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      id="firstgrade"
                      name="firstgrade"
                      value={formData.firstgrade}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <label
                      className="inline_label"
                      htmlFor="firstgrade"
                      id="firstgrade"
                    >
                      1. klasse
                    </label>
                  </section>
                  <section className="class">
                    {" "}
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      id="secondgrade"
                      name="secondgrade"
                      value={formData.secondgrade}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <label
                      className="inline_label"
                      htmlFor="secondgrade"
                      id="secondgrade"
                    >
                      2. klasse
                    </label>
                  </section>
                  <section className="class">
                    {" "}
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      id="thirdgrade"
                      name="thirdgrade"
                      value={formData.thirdgrade}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <label
                      className="inline_label"
                      htmlFor="thirdgrade"
                      id="thirdgrade"
                    >
                      3. klasse
                    </label>
                  </section>
                  <section className="class">
                    {" "}
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      id="fourthgrade"
                      name="fourthgrade"
                      value={formData.fourthgrade}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <label
                      className="inline_label"
                      htmlFor="fourthgrade"
                      id="fourthgrade"
                    >
                      4. klasse
                    </label>{" "}
                  </section>
                  <section className="class">
                    {" "}
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      id="fifthgrade"
                      name="fifthgrade"
                      value={formData.fifthgrade}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <label
                      className="inline_label"
                      htmlFor="fifthgrade"
                      id="fifthgrade"
                    >
                      5. klasse
                    </label>
                  </section>
                  <section className="class">
                    {" "}
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      id="sixthgrade"
                      name="sixthgrade"
                      value={formData.sixthgrade}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <label
                      className="inline_label"
                      htmlFor="sixthgrade"
                      id="sixthgrade"
                    >
                      6. klasse
                    </label>{" "}
                  </section>
                  <section className="class">
                    {" "}
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      id="seventhgrade"
                      name="seventhgrade"
                      value={formData.seventhgrade}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <label
                      className="inline_label"
                      htmlFor="seventhgrade"
                      id="seventhgrade"
                    >
                      7. klasse
                    </label>
                  </section>
                </section>
                <h2 className="form_h2">Opplysninger om foresatte - mor</h2>
                <label htmlFor="mom_name" id="mom_name">
                  Fullt navn
                </label>
                <input
                  className="apply_input"
                  type="text"
                  id="mom_name"
                  name="mom_name"
                  value={formData.mom_name}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="mom_adress" id="mom_adress">
                  Evt annen adresse
                </label>
                <input
                  className="apply_input"
                  type="text"
                  id="mom_adress"
                  name="mom_adress"
                  value={formData.mom_adress}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <div className="post_group">
                  <label htmlFor="mom_postnr" id="mom_postnr">
                    Postnummer
                  </label>
                  <input
                    className="apply_input"
                    type="text"
                    id="mom_postnr"
                    name="mom_postnr"
                    value={formData.mom_postnr}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />{" "}
                </div>
                <div className="post_group">
                  <label htmlFor="mom_city" id="mom_city">
                    Poststed
                  </label>
                  <input
                    className="apply_input"
                    type="text"
                    id="mom_city"
                    name="mom_city"
                    value={formData.mom_city}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <label htmlFor="mom_phone" id="mom_phone">
                  Telefon
                </label>
                <input
                  className="apply_input"
                  type="text"
                  id="mom_phone"
                  name="mom_phone"
                  value={formData.mom_phone}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="mom_email" id="mom_email">
                  Epost
                </label>
                <input
                  className="apply_input"
                  type="text"
                  id="mom_email"
                  name="mom_email"
                  value={formData.mom_email}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <h2 className="form_h2">Andre opplysninger</h2>
                <label htmlFor="children_age" id="children_age">
                  Alder på andre barn i familien
                </label>
                <input
                  className="apply_input"
                  type="text"
                  id="children_age"
                  name="children_age"
                  value={formData.children_age}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="other" id="other">
                  Andre opplysninger som er relevante for søknaden:
                </label>
                <textarea
                  className="apply_textarea"
                  id="other"
                  name="other"
                  value={formData.other}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="why" id="why">
                  Hvorfor ønsker dere plass hos oss?{" "}
                </label>
                <textarea
                  className="apply_textarea"
                  id="why"
                  name="why"
                  value={formData.why}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />{" "}
                <legend>Samtykke</legend>
                <section className="class">
                  <input
                    className="checkbox"
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="consent"
                    name="consent"
                    value={formData.consent}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                  <label className="inline_consent">
                    lorem ipsum
                  </label>
                </section>
                <button
                  className="apply_btn"
                  type="submit"
                  id="button"
                  value="Submit"
                >
                  Send søknad
                </button>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
            {formError && <p className="setFormError">{formError}</p>}
            {formSuccess && <p className="setFormSuccess">{formSuccess}</p>}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};
```

Do I need to set a State for the checkbox or is it another way to register the value?
The value is not being registered so the output doesn't show up in the Emailjs template, even tho I used the {{consent}} id.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).